# JAVA - Read configuration file from Eclipse and JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I need to properly set the path (or the tree structure in Eclipse) to read a configuration file both in a development environment (Eclipse) and production environment (by running a jar file).

Currently, I read the file in two ways:

```
 -  public String getProperty(String parameter) {
       String property = null;
       try {
        //prop.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("configuration.properties"));

          prop.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("src/configuration.properties"));
          property = prop.getProperty(parameter);
       } 
       catch (IOException e) {
          e.getMessage();
       }
       return property;
    }

 - try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
      ...
   }
```

The problem is with the first method: in Eclipse I have to set

```
getResourceAsStream("configuration.properties"));
```

while for jar I have to add src

```
getResourceAsStream("src/configuration.properties"));
```

since the jar file is located at the same level of a src folder containing the configuration file.

For the FileReader method the src/configuration.properties path works fine in both cases.

In Eclipse I have the following tree structure:

```
ProjectName
+ src/
     + filePackage/
            FileLoader.java
     + config_file
```

How could I manage both cases using a common approach/path?

Thanks

Comment: What if you provide it as an argument?

Comment: @Justas What and where?

Comment: When you start your program, you could add an argument E.g. `--configuration file.properties` and you would use that path to load it.

Comment: @Justas Isn't there a way to manage it by code? Now, I have to remember to change path before creating the jar file. It's not a great effort, but if I could  manage it by code...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by changing paths. Another idea is to have a default configuration which resides in the jar, and user provided which would override the one in the jar.

Comment: @Justas When I run the application in Eclipse the path must be "file_name.txt", while when I run the jar I have to add "src/file_name.txt". Maybe the issue is the "getResourceAsStream" call?

Comment: No, it's not an issue with the method. But rather with how you package your jar. `src` folder should not be present in the jar. How are you building your jar?